# ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to implement a POC in spring dataflow. I am using "spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local" dependency to create dataflow server in local. But it is giving below error :

```
 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.ms.batch_ui.App.main(App.java:14)
```

Below is pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ms</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>abc-ui</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.193</h2.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And I have very basic java file to launch the app

```
@EnableDataFlowServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class,args);
    }
}
```

I think the error might be due to version compatibility issues between dataflow server-local and spring boot, but I am not able to find the correct version.
I have also searched in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/releases, but spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local is not given here.

Please help me with correct version matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Cloud Data Flow release - **Edgware.SR4**. Its Compatible with **Spring Boot 1.5.14**.

For Example: Hoxton.SR8 (spring cloud version) compatible with 2.3.3.RELEASE(spring boot)
**Reference**: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/releases?after=v1.7.4.RELEASE

You are getting the above Exception, because you did not add the spring cloud `dependencyMangement` block. But you need a dependency management block for spring cloud (this block is required for a spring cloud technologies - bunch of technologies like spring cloud ribbon, spring cloud zuul & so on).

Add this also,

```
<properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I recommend you create a spring boot project using [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io), add required dependencies, choose your spring boot required version, which gives spring cloud compatible versions, instead of manually selecting on your own.

**Note**:
you can check all the compatible versions(spring boot & spring cloud data flow) in the same page by scrolling down & using next button